# NetLogo HPC Memory error

Tags: java, netlogo

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N para_three
#$ -q all.q
#$ -pe mpi 30
/home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
    --model /home/abhishekb/models/try4.nlogo \
    --experiment experiment1 \
    --table /home/abhishekb/csvresults/24.04_Results.csv
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "JobThread" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JobThread"
Exception in thread "JobThread" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JobThread"
Exception in thread "JobThread" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JobThread"
```

Why, I don't understand?I found advice on running NetLogo with 64bit java. But the link[[1]](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/conversations/topics/15803)[[2]](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/master/dist/netlogo.sh) has expired, please help.

Surprisingly, earlier I was running it on NetLogo 5.1 and never got this error.

Script Change:
I tried to add threads at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N para_three
#$ -q all.q
#$ -pe mpi 30
/home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh \
    --model /home/abhishekb/models/try4.nlogo \
    --experiment experiment1 \
    --table /home/abhishekb/csvresults/24.04_Results.csv \
    --threads 30
```

New error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:27)
    at org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadBytecodeClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:32)
    at org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.finish(Generator.scala:241)
```

Edit 3:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "`dirname "$0"`"             # the copious quoting is for handling paths with spaces
#-Xmx3000m                     use up to 1GB RAM (edit to increase)
# -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8         ensure Unicode characters in model files are compatible cross-platform
# -classpath NetLogo.jar        specify main jar
# org.nlogo.headless.Main       specify we want headless, not GUI
# "$@"                          pass along any command line arguments
-XX:MaxPermSize=3200m          avoid OutOfMemory errors for large models
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath NetLogo.jar org.nlogo.headless.Main "$@"
```

Error:

> /home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh: line 8: -XX:MaxPermSize=3200m: command not found 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)   at
>   org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:27)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.CustomClassLoader.loadBytecodeClass(CustomClassLoader.scala:32)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.finish(Generator.scala:241)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generate(Generator.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator.org$nlogo$generator$Generator$$recurse(Generator.scala:28)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateOldStyleCall$1.apply(Generator.scala:208)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateOldStyleCall$1.apply(Generator.scala:208)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.map(ArrayOps.scala:38)     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateOldStyleCall(Generator.scala:208)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:146)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateInstruction$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Generator.scala:167)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateInstruction$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Generator.scala:167)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateInstruction$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Generator.scala:167)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:81)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator$$anonfun$generateInstruction$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Generator.scala:167)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateBodyMethod(Generator.scala:115)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generate(Generator.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.nlogo.generator.Generator.org$nlogo$generator$Generator$$recurse(Generator.scala:28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to PermGen, so that means the problem isn't the total size of the heap, but rather the PermGen ceiling specifically. You'll need to start Java with a higher PermGen setting, e.g. `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. There may already be such a setting in your `netlogo-headless.sh` file; if so, increase it. If there isn't such a setting there already, add one.

I'm about 98% sure this has nothing to do with any difference between NetLogo 5.1 and 5.2. There is probably something else different about what you're doing now with 5.2 and what you were doing then with 5.1 (perhaps the size of the `threads=` setting).

Here are working links to the default `netlogo.sh` and `netlogo-headless.sh` files for NetLogo 5.2: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.2.0/dist/netlogo.sh, https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.2.0/dist/netlogo-headless.sh

Running a 64-bit JVM isn't specifically relevant to resolving a PermGen issue, but may be necessary for running with a very large heap.

Comment: I have this setting `# -Xmx1024m                     use up to 1GB RAM (edit to increase)
`

Comment: I still can't seem to solve the problem.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Does your latest script have a `-XX:MaxPermSize=` setting in it?

Comment: My advice boils down to "you need to set `-XX:MaxPermSize`", but you don't seem to have set it. `-XX:MaxPermSize` and `-Xmx` are not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did what you said it shows me this error `/home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh: Command not found.` Please check edit 2.

Comment: I am adding it incorrectly. Please let me know. Sorry for bothering again.

Comment: If possible can you add how an `netlogo.headless.sh` should like after adding `-XX:MaxPermSize`. I have tried several different additions . Stil stuck with `home/abhishekb/netlogo/netlogo-5.2.0/netlogo-headless.sh: Command not found.`

Comment: In shell scripts, lines that begin with `#` are just comments. Everything in them is ignored by the script.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply I tried to uncomment them, I get the same error. Can you please post the correct way the file should look like.

Comment: Please the edit 3 for code and the error following your previosu advice. Thanks!

Comment: `-XX:MaxPermSize` is an argument to the `java` command. It goes after `java`, not before, as shown in my gist.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. Don't know what was I thinking.